# Bootstrap responsive não quebra para linha de baixo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

tenho o seguinte código:

```html
    <div class="welcome-content row">
      <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <%= image_tag('feed/welcome2016.jpg') %>
      </figure>
      <p class="welcome-text col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sodales placerat vestibulum. Vivamus in pretium lorem. Mauris rutrum tempus neque sit amet aliquam. Ut vel mi pulvinar, condimentum nisl non, lobortis purus. Praesent ullamcorper purus dui, a feugiat lacus vestibulum vel. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. mentum nisl non, lobortis purus. Praesent ullamcorper purus dui, a feugiat lacus vestibulum vel. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. el. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. el. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. tis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. tis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. tis. Donec porttitor lacus libero.
      </p>
    </div>
```

porem quando vou diminuindo o tamanho da tela ele não quebra o bloco de texto para linha de baixo ficando a imagem em cima e o texto em baixo.

Talvez seja algo fácil mas eu não estou enxergando :S .

Comment: Não consegui te entender, o que você quer exatamente?

Comment: @SamirBraga quando redimensiono a tela o certo seria o texto correr para baixo da figura, porem não esta correndo isso =/

Comment: A resposta do Marcelo não lhe serve?

Comment: @SamirBraga o exemplo dele funcionou porem aplicando aqui no meu não funcionou, deve ser algum detalhe besta, o estranho que nos outros elementos funciona direitinho apenas nesse não, ou seja, não é problema no bootstrap

Comment: Você possei algum estilo local que mecha com algum desses elementos?

Comment: Sim eu tenho uma folha de estilo próprio para o bloco aonde esta esse código. @SamirBraga

Comment: Melhor postá-lo para darmos uma olhada. Você acha que o problema pode morar lá?

Comment: @SamirBraga  achei o problema era em um css mesmo, tirei e deu certo =D muito obrigado me ajudou man

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado... :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que o problema esteja por estar colocando em uma tag p, fiz uma pequena alteração e ve se resolve.

```
<div class="welcome-content row">
    <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/">
    </figure>
    <div class="welcome-text col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sodales placerat vestibulum. Vivamus in pretium lorem. Mauris rutrum tempus neque sit amet aliquam. Ut vel mi pulvinar, condimentum nisl non, lobortis purus. Praesent ullamcorper purus dui, a feugiat lacus vestibulum vel. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. mentum nisl non, lobortis purus. Praesent ullamcorper purus dui, a feugiat lacus vestibulum vel. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. el. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. el. Vestibulum tincidunt ac lectus in venenatis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. tis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. tis. Donec porttitor lacus libero. tis. Donec porttitor lacus libero.
    </div>
</div>
```

segue rodando no jsfiddle o [resultado](http://jsfiddle.net/sjzh4k3m/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: Então no seu exemplo deu certo, mas aqui mesmo mudando para div não deu certo =/  estranho ta certinho EU ACHO!!!

Answer (score 1):

Graças a ajuda do Marcelo e do Samir fucei no código e percebi que estava usando o código abaixo para centralizar o objeto na vertical e isso estava interferindo no elemento e ocasionando o problema que mencionei acima, retirei esses estilos e deu tudo certo.

```css
  .welcome-content
  {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Obrigado a todos